# How to select duplicate values from a list

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I have this Request class as my object -

```
public class Request {
      int id;
      String name;
      String address;
      String mobileNumber;
    }
```

And I have this list of requests (List of above Request object)-

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList();

Request1 = new Request(1, "peter", "mumbai", "9439264054");
Request2 = new Request(2, "peter", "mumbai", "9439264054");
Request3 = new Request(3, "martin", "navi mumbai", "9004415857");
Request3 = new Request(4, "parker", "nagpur", "9004415856");


requests.add(Request1); 
requests.add(Request2); 
requests.add(Request3); 
requests.add(Request4);
```

Now I want to filter only the duplicate rows based on **name, address and mobileNumber** 
Basically when I filter, my result should **contain only Request1 and Request2**.

What would be my ideal approach using java 8 or simple for loop?

Comment: You'll have to add the class structure for better context. when is a request duplicate, when all fields except id are equal? (You'll have to write a function that indicates duplicate/equals)

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram Hi, I just edited my question. Hope this clears some air. Let know if you need further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a key method to identify objects and compare them for duplication.

See the snippet below, I use '_' as delimiter as name and phone number would not contain this character

```
private class Request {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String address;
    private final String mobileNumber;

    public Request(final int id, final String name, final String address, final String mobileNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return name + "_" + address+ "_" + mobileNumber;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Request{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", mobileNumber='" + mobileNumber + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The list can be grouped by the key function, i.e, all requests with the same key will be grouped together. Now, we can retrieve the lists with more than one element in it to find the duplicates. See the snippet below that can be used for your example.

```
    requests.add(Request1); requests.add(Request2); requests.add(Request3); requests.add(Request4);
    final List<Request> duplicateRequests = requests.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Request::getKey)) // group requests by key
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) // If duplicates exist
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // get the duplicate values
            .flatMap(List::stream) // collect the duplicates in a new list
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can then print the duplicates' list with the below snippet:

```
    duplicateRequests.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

And the printed output is:

```
Request{id=1, name='peter', address='mumbai', mobileNumber='9439264054'}
Request{id=2, name='peter', address='mumbai', mobileNumber='9439264054'}
```

Comment: Hey Man. This solution really worked. I am able to find out duplicates now. You are a savior :)

Comment: However I saw one issue with this approach.
take a look at below example
Request1 = new Request(1, "peter", "mumbai", "9439264054");
Request2 = new Request(2, "peter", "mumbai", "9439264054");
Request3 = new Request(3, "martin", "navi mumbai", "9004415857");
Request4 = new Request(4, "martin", "navi mumbai", "9004415857");

This won't return Request1, Request2, Request3, Request4. It will only return Request1 and Request2

Comment: Yeah, you can replace the findFirst().get with the snippet below:

                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());